# Using the wires in an HDMI cable for carrying power?

Tags: power, stepper-motor, hdmi

Could I use an HDMI cable in conjunction with a breakout board on  both ends to drive several stepper motors all through one cable? Or do the wires have special properties that would make them unsuitable for this purpose? My current setup is rat's nest :D

(Assuming of course that I don't exceed the limits of the 24-gauge wire or whatever it is)

Comment: Providing you are within the current limit of the wire and connector, all should be ok. In general however it is not good practice to use 'Standard' cables for alternative purposes since it's easy for users to plug in wrong equipment. In your case a mistake might easily fry a monitor incorrectly plugged in.

Comment: It may be possible but why would you use HDMI cable for that? The connector pin is quite small that it will be a little bit hard to catch inner wires and connect. I would recommend using an ethernet cable for this purpose. It will be much easier to connect and there are already example delivering power over ethernet, called [PoE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet)

Comment: @BumsikKim Well, an HDMI cable has double the wires that an Ethernet cable does

Comment: you can double the wires to double the capacity; HDMI has plenty...

Comment: I would recommend a cable with DA-15, DB-25, or DE-15? These are all easy to obtain, use inexpensive, easy to solder connectors, and can carry more current (depending on the cable construction) than those teeny diff-pairs in HDMI. DSubs are nice because they span everything from 9 pins to at least 62 pins, and are pretty hardy.